# How to start using Qgis python console

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

I'm new with python and I'm new with GDAL, so this is a dual problem.

I would like to start using the QGIS python console, in order to carry out some recurring operation.
I tried with this easy script

```
import gdal
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -s_srs EPSG:32630 -t_srs EPSG:3035 -r near -of GTiff /home/giacomo/Scrivania/provas/cccp.dat /home/giacomo/Scrivania/provas/cccp_qgs2.tif
```

But what I get is this syntax error:

> File "", line 1
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import os
os.system('gdalwarp -ot Float32 -s_srs EPSG:32630 -t_srs EPSG:3035 -r near -of GTiff /home/giacomo/Scrivania/provas/cccp.dat /home/giacomo/Scrivania/provas/cccp_qgs2.tif')
```

Comment: Dear Francisco it works. Thank you very much. Have a nice day